# VB.net - Timer isn't updating

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm trying to add an uptime counter so that from the moment my application launches it starts a timer that increments by the second until the application is closed or I stop it on purpose.

Currently the timer counts the first second and then stops. This might be me not understanding the tick function? I assume that the interval I set for the timer will refresh or loop the code within the tick sub? (Could me massively wrong).

I have timer1 and I've set it to `"Enabled"` and the interval to `"1000"` for one second.

In my `Timer1_Tick Sub` I have this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim seconds, minutes, hours As Integer
    If seconds = 60 Then
        seconds = 0
        minutes = minutes + 1
    End If

    If minutes = 60 Then
        If seconds = 60 Then
            seconds = 0
            minutes = 0
            hours = hours + 1
        End If
    End If
    seconds = seconds + 1
    Label44.Text = Format(hours, "00") & "." & Format(minutes, "00") & "." & Format(seconds, "00")
End Sub
```

In `Form1_Load` I have `Timer1.Start()`

Please can you tell me what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Seconds is declared locally in the Tick event, so the value is going to get reinitialized each pass. Your label will only ever show 1 second. You can confirm this by putting a break point in the tick event code and seeing it stop every second.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that because I declared the seconds, minutes and hours string within the tick event it will keep being reloaded? I need to for example declare these within form1_load or perhaps another class?

Comment: @Sam You could declare them globally (above the function)

Comment: @Sam You need to declare them as member variables within the class. Variables declared within a function are scoped only to that function. They are inaccessible from other functions and are released back to memory when the function terminates. If you want to use the values across function calls, you must declare them at a higher scope.

Comment: This approach is not accurate because the tick event may or may not fire exactly on the interval specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables within `Form1`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private seconds, minutes, hours As Integer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick    
        If seconds = 60 Then
            seconds = 0
            minutes = minutes + 1
        End If

        If minutes = 60 Then
            If seconds = 60 Then
                seconds = 0
                minutes = 0
                hours = hours + 1
            End If
        End If
        seconds = seconds + 1
        Label44.Text = Format(hours, "00") & "." & Format(minutes, "00") & "." & Format(seconds, "00")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This approach is not accurate because the tick event may or may not fire exactly on the interval specified.

Comment: True, I have up-voted the other answers. But the question doesn't ask for the best approach, it's just asking why the chosen approach isn't working.

Comment: If the chosen approach is supposed to provide meaningful data, i.e. elapsed time, then it will never work.  We can only hope others with similar needs will read all of the posts.

Answer (score 3):

For up time in my applications I just log the time and date it was started, then use a label to show difference in time since the time was logged. It's a lot simpler than running a time ticking all the time.

Comment: You still need a timer in this instance in order to update the label (unless you tie it into another regular event), but it's at least less resource heavy - you can just run it every minute or so instead of every second.

Answer (score 3):

The approaches given are highly inaccurate because they assume that the tick event fires exactly at the specified interval, and that doesn't happen.

The tick event should be used only to update the label from a more precise time measurement.  In the code below a stopwatch is used.

```
Dim appruntime As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = appruntime.Elapsed.ToString("d\ hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub
```